# The LiveReload extension for Middleman is reloading the entire page instead of just the CSS.

Tags: middleman, livereload

When I use the LiveReload mac's app it works as it's supposed to. So it's not really a problem but can't help but think I'm missing something obvious.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?